# How to generate only API_KEY and USER_SECRET in with laravel passport

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-passport

I am developing api using laravel passport. But i have tried using the various grant types, the authorization code, password grants, client credentials but still not getting the desired result i want. Maybe i am not able to understand well. Looking at stripe, after you signup, you get api key and a secret which you use in your application. How do I achieve same result using passport where after user signup, user get API_KEY and USER_SECRET to use in his application.

Comment: This doesn't help you ? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport

Comment: did you find a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate `passport:keys` you need to execute:

```
php artisan passport:keys
```

More you can read [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#deploying-passport).

Also, you will need to create client with:

```
php artisan passport:client
```

More in [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#managing-clients).

Comment: If I update the keys using `php artisan passport:keys --force` (just to get new keys) do I still have to re-create the client? If so, how to find the client ID?

Comment: you can find clients in `oauth_clients` table.

Comment: Thanks, there are two clients one is a personal access client without a provider and the other is a password client with a "user" provider. I'm dealing with an application that I didn't create, so this is new to me. Which client should I choose? I suspect the latter client that has "password_client" set to 1. Am I correct?

Comment: I guess we both aren't sure in that matter. Also, my question was wrong, it asks "Which user ID should the client be assigned to?" and then it asks for a name for the client. Unfortunately, the Laravel docs do not give me answers as well.

Comment: In my projects `user_id` is `null`. And the name is simple `PROJECT_NAME Password Grant Client` and Authentication works for me.